# Boundedness Theorem Proof Question

Tags: real-analysis

I have gone through the entire proof of the Boundedness Theorem on this [site](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/boundedness-theorem). I am stuck on essentially the last sentence of this proof :(

> I do not understand why $|f(x_{n_k})|>n_k\geq k$ holds true for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$? Why does this step work?

[image]

Comment: You need to prove $n_k \geq k$ from $1 \leq n_1 < n_2 < \dots$, You can easily prove this by induction from the following : $n_k \geq 1$, and you also have $n_{k+1} \geq n_k + 1$.

Comment: and if you have any question why $|f(x_{n_k})| > n_k$, it's a part of the way $x_n$ was defined.

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri I get the $n_k\geq k$ now! I would not have thought that worked like that. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $n_1 \geq 1$ and $n_{k+1} \geq n_k + 1$ it follows $n_k \geq k.$